# AJAX post returns HTML tags with the particular value

Tags: php, jquery, json, post

I'm trying to write a code that adds user comment using jquery's post.I passed parameters  to ajax.php  and received josn data, as the following:

```
var formObjectData = $('#' + form_id).serialize() + '&flag=add_comment'; // all 
$.post(
    'http://192.168.3.3/myblog/ajax.php',formObjectData,
    function(data) {
        if (!data)
            alert("No data");
        else {
            if (data.msg!='')
                $("#add_comment").html(data.msg);
        }
    },
    'json'
);
```

on ajax.php

```
$cid = $classobj->add_comment($comment,$id); // to add the comment in db and return the comment id
$ajax['msg'] = $msg ? $msg : '';
if ($cid) {
    $ajax['cid'] = $cid;
}
echo json_encode($ajax);
```

My problem is the jquery returns many irreverent html tags  wihth the json data as the below

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
    </head>
</html>{"msg":"hello","cid":"600"}
```

what is the easest way to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: post your ajax.php full code? something problem with it.

Comment: Isn't $classobj>add_comment this supposed to be $classobj -> add_comment ?

Comment: Don't you have another `echo` statement elsewhere ? Try commenting `echo json_encode($ajax);` and see what result you get. Or try putting `exit` right after your `echo` and look at the result.

Answer (score 0):

If your ajax.php file contains any style or HTML, you will be given that data back when you perform your AJAX request. Remove any styling or HTML from your ajax endpoint. A simple way is to `exit()` or `die()` after the JSON encode (if there is HTML after it) or just remove it totally.

Also, remember to include the following code before `json_encode($ajax)`:

`header('Content-Type: application/json');` - this will ensure it is always recognised as a JSON object. I know Chrome certainly has problems inferring what your sending back is actually JSON!